# Raspberry PI ArchLinux telnet server 4 times Login incorrect

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, login, telnet

I installed via `pacman -S inetutils` telnet and want to try to login via telnet but if i use `telnet localhost` to connect

This comes up

```
[root@alarmpi ~]# systemctl restart telnet.socket
[root@alarmpi ~]# telnet localhost
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Linux 5.10.38-2-ARCH (alarmpi) (pts/1)

Login incorrect

Login incorrect

Login incorrect

Login incorrect


Login incorrect

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I already googled a lot and just found https://www.toolbox.com/tech/operating-systems/question/problems-using-telnet-to-access-a-solaris-8-server-032008/ but without any solution

My `/etc/xinetd/telnet`

```
service telnet
{
        flags                   = REUSE
        socket_type             = stream
        wait                    = no
        user                    = root
        server                  = /usr/bin/telnetd
        log_on_failure          += USERID
        disable                 = no
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

If not, install `pacman -S xinetd`
and change in `nano /etc/xinetd/telnet`

```
service telnet
{
        flags                   = REUSE
        socket_type             = stream
        wait                    = no
        user                    = root
        server                  = /usr/bin/telnetd
        server_args             = --exec-login=/usr/bin/login
        log_on_failure          += USERID
        disable                 = no
}
```

then do `systemctl stop telnet.socket` and `systemctl start xinetd`

http://polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=telnetd&tf=2&of=Archlinux&sf=8

--exec-login=STRING: set program to be executed instead of /usr/bin/login